How can I use 3rd party JS libraries when developing a chrome extension?
I am looking to use 3rd party js libraries like Chart.js in my chrome extension.
Chart.js provides two options for leveraging the library

Via CDN (there are issues regarding Manifest v3 security policy)
Via NPM (I also don't think this is supported)

I've also seen some hacky workarounds like sandboxing the page but this would remove access to the chrome extension api which my extension heavily leverages.
What can be done?

npm can be use - explore check

You have to download them to the source directory and put them in the <head>, same as a CDN.  <script type="text/javascript" src="./chartjs/chart.js"></script> etc...  Extensions are picky.  You can't have ANY in-line code, not even CSS. Here's Copy Emoji extension I made, for an example.
